# Sorting Digital Ocean proplets

Tags: cloud, digital-ocean

I have droplets on DO, and want to delete the ones that are older than 1day. Is there such filer to only get the ones older than X days when using `doctl compute droplet list` or `doctl compute droplet delete`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the golang client you can access the create time of the droplet

ref: https://github.com/digitalocean/godo/blob/c76ad00599db25c5b917622b71c2622ca6025ccf/droplets.go#L60